# How to grep a shell variable for values present in psql output?

Tags: shell, csv, grep, psql

Here'a short summary on what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have a CSV stored as a $variable in shell. It looks like this:

```
account,index,quantity
100,AAPL,10
105,NFLX,25
110,TSLA,50
120,TWTR,45
```

Now I query a PSQL db from shell as such:

```
accounts=$(psql -d mydb -h mydb -f "SELECT account_num FROM accounts WHERE is_relevant")
```

Now I have a list of accounts, stored in a seemingly unstructured variable. **Simply, I want to filter my original CSV for the values given in my new accounts query.**

1) When I call echo on the variable storing my query result, I get a long string of output - just a concatenated list of all relevant accounts.

2) When I call head on the variable, each account number throws an error:

```
head: cannot open '100' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I see this, and I think, "shell is not recognizing these entries as strings to print, but rather commands to run" - and I'm not sure how to fix this. Attempts to use sed to place quotes or commas to delimit the strings have thrown similar errors - either regarding missing files or nonexistent commands.

While I suspect grep is ultimately the correct tool for this - I want to pose this open-endedly. How would you do this?

Edit: to clarify, given my original account table, if the PSQL query returns:

```
100
105
120
```

I want to filter the original table on these values, to obtain:

```
account,index,quantity
100,AAPL,10
105,NFLX,25
120,TWTR,45
```

(Row with account # 110 has been filtered out.)

Comment: How are you echoing `accounts`? I suspect you're not using quotes.

Comment: Within the shell script ---

    accounts=$(psql -d mydb -h mydb -f "SELECT account_num FROM accounts WHERE is_relevant")  //  


    echo $accounts
---

Result: ---

    100 105 110

Comment: You're missing the quotes - try `echo "$accounts"`

Comment: Just a couple of things. (1) When you call `head $accounts` is like you are calling `head 100 105 110`, and therefore `head` will look for files named _100_, _105_ and _110_ that don't exist. It will be almost the same if you use `head "$accounts"`, with the difference that it will look for a file named _100 105 110_. (2) You can loop the query result using a _foreach_: `for account in $accounts; do #filter for each account returned in the query; done`.

Comment: If you add representative output of your `psql` command and the output you're trying to get in the end (i.e., add a [mcve]), we can help you better.

Comment: Representative output of my SQL command is a list of accounts - the result of selecting some subset of all of accounts based on a where clause. I.e. (arranged vertically), 100 105 110. The output I want is my original table filtered on these values - I would imagine this is done with grep. I will amend my original question to include an example result.

Comment: Nestor - that makes sense conceptually; does shell have a clean way to combine all of these separate filters? If I do these filters row-by-row, in sequence on the same file, will I not end up with a blank file? I.e., first all accounts != 100 are filtered (leaving only account # 100), then all accounts != 105 are filtered (leaving 0 remaining accounts) - and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this after the query:

```
# Create a filtered_variable to store the filtered results
# and add the first line from the original variable (the CSV header)
filtered_variable=$(echo "$variable" | head -n 1)

# For each account in the accounts obtained in the query
for account in $accounts
do
    # Create a filtered_line variable to store the line where the account
    # appears in the CSV, or an empty line if the account is not in the CSV
    filtered_line=$(echo "$variable" | grep "^$account,")

    # If $filtered_line is not empty (the account is in the CSV) ...
    if [ ! -z "$filtered_line" ]
    then
        # ... add the line to the filtered_variable (filtered CSV)
        filtered_variable+=$'\n'"$filtered_line"
    fi
done
```

Now you have the filtered table in the variable `filtered_variable`. If you want it in the original `variable`, then just do `variable="$filtered_variable"` after the loop.

**Alternative solution**

You can also use `egrep` with a regex that includes all the accounts returned in the query. For instance

```
echo "$variable" | egrep -e "^100,|^110,"
```

will return

```
100,AAPL,10
110,TSLA,50
```

This regex looks for lines starting with `100,` or `110,`. I have added the `,` to avoid false possitive matches.

So all you need is to create that regex for all the accounts returned in the query. This can be done easily with `sed`:

```
filter=$(echo "^$accounts," | sed -e 's/ /,|^/g')
```

Now you have your filter as a regex in the variable `filter`, and all that remains is to do the `egrep`:

```
filtered_variable=$(echo "$variable" | egrep "$filter")
```

And again you will have the filtered accounts in the auxiliar variable `filtered_variable` (don't forget to add the CSV header line first).

Comment: Hi Nestor - my fault if this wasn't clear, but there may be more than one entry with a given account number in my original table (i.e., 100 AAPL 50 and 100 SPY 25 in the same table as separate entries). I'm not sure if your first solution accommodates for this - but it looks like your second solution does (and is generalized such that I do not have to hard code the account numbers!).

Comment: Hi @nreminder. If I understand it correctly, you mean that the CSV can have multiple lines for the same account number. And in that case you want all the lines to be included in the filtered variable. If so, the first proposed solution still works, as you can try in http://rextester.com/UMWMV30704

Comment: Got it - in your line filtered_line=$(echo "$variable" | grep "$account"), do you mean to grep on "account" (the loop variable)?

Comment: Yes, that's it. That line looks for matches of `"$account"` in `"$variable"`, and stores the result in `filtered_line`. You can modify the pattern used in `grep` to just look for lines that start with `"$account"` and include the `,` to avoid also false possitives. I'm going to update the answer to include this last improvement.